# Conflicting ESLint config using TypeScript and Prettier in a Nuxt project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, nuxt.js, prettier

I'm trying to set-up ESLint and Prettier for my TypeScript Nuxt.js project. Unfortunately the combination of some ESLint configs produces strange errors.

The example file below validates fine using just prettier from the command line. However using ESLint I get the following error:

```
  2:10  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token
  1 | export default class User {
> 2 |   public name: string;
    |          ^
  3 | }
```

Strangely if I remove the `plugin:vue/recommended` extend from my ESLint config, the example file validates just fine. To me it looks like there is a conflict or override that messes with TypeScript files, but I can't figure out exactly what the issue is and how to fix it.

Example file `User.ts`:

```
export default class User {
  public name: string;
}
```

ESLint config:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      legacyDecorators: true
    }
  },
  extends: [
    'typescript',
    'plugin:vue/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'prettier/vue'
  ],
  plugins: [
    'prettier',
    'vue'
  ],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'error'
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using nuxt 2.4.0?

Comment: For what it is worth, I am also trying NuxtTS+ESLint. [Here is my eslintrc](https://github.com/Al-un/nuxt-ts/blob/master/.eslintrc.js). I am not posting an answer as I haven't tried with more components and stuff